# (Beginner) Determining if an input character is a digit using guards in Haskell

Tags: haskell

How could we determine if an input character is a digit using guards in Haskell? This is what I came up with,

```
test :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> Bool
test a
  | elem a [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]  = True
  | otherwise = False
```

However, when given a Char it returns : "error: Variable not in scope: a". How could I modify this in order to have it take characters as input too?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you entering this in GHCi? You should get a type error, since a `Char` does not have a `Num` instance.

Comment: `test :: Char -> Bool`, and check if `a` is in `"123456789"`.

Comment: There is no need for guards here: once you fix the call, `elem` already returns the boolean value you need. Don't write `f x | condition = True | otherwise = False`, use `f x = condition`.

Answer (score 1):

> However, when given a Char it returns : `"error: Variable not in scope: a`

If you use a `Char`, you need to use `test 'a'`, not `test a`. This will however *not* work. Indeed, the type signature is:

```
test :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> Bool
```

it thus works with *numerical* types. For a `Char`, you will need to work with:

```
test :: Char -> Bool
test = a `elem` …
```

where I leave filling in the `…` part as an exercise, this should be a foldable of `Char`s, for example a `String`.